# Is there any way that a type can be saved inside a Scala list?

Tags: scala

I was trying to create something like a **`FilterList`** with an `Enumeration` called **`FilterType`**.

`FilterList` should have a list of `(filterValue, ClassOfValue, FilterType)` tuples, for example

```
val listOfFilters: List[(String, ???, FilterType)] = List(
  ("fromDate", String, DateFilter),
  ("toDate", String, DateFilter),
  ("id", Long, IdFilter)
)
```

The main reason for this is to read that filter from and write that filter to JSON with something like:

```
(__ \ filterName).read[ClassOfValue]
```

The problem is that I have not found a way to replace the `???` and I don't even know if it is possible in Scala.

**edit:**

**Intellij IDEA** suggest me to specify it as an `Object`, but it doesn't feel like there should be a `Class` reference:

```
val listOfFilters: List[(String, Object, FilterType)] = List(
  ("fromDate", String, DateFilter),
  ("toDate", String, DateFilter),
  ("id", Long, IdFilter)
)
```

Comment: How about `Any`.

Comment: `Any` is an acceptable replacement as it should compile, but isn't there any specifier for a class? With `Any` you can add for example a String value like `"a string"`, and in that case the JSON call would not work

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to make another Enum for the `ClassOfValue` and then pattern match on that Enum when you want to do `(__ \ filterName).read[ClassOfValue]`?

Comment: @evan058 That's a good idea, indeed. The main requirement is to allow just very general classes like `String`, `Long`, `Double` and `Boolean` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than creating an enum value for each type of `ClassOfValue`, you could also make a `Filter` class which takes the `ClassOfValue` as a type parameter. This filter class would then handle its own JSON input/output. It would look something like this:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, typeOf}

object FilterType extends Enumeration
{
    type FilterType = Value
    val DateFilter, IdFilter = Value
}

import FilterType._

case class Filter[A](filterValue: String, filterType: FilterType)(implicit tt: TypeTag[A])
{
    def myTypeParam: Unit = println(s"My Type Param is ${typeOf[A]}")

    def applyFilter(data: A): A = ???
}


val l: List[Filter[_]] = List(Filter[String]("fromDate", DateFilter), 
                         Filter[String]("toDate", DateFilter), Filter[Long]("id", IdFilter))

l.foreach(_.myTypeParam)

/*
    Output: 
    My Type Param is String
    My Type Param is String
    My Type Param is Long
*/
```

So in that `applyFilter` method you would have something like `<LOOKUP FILTER VALUE>.read[A]` and then `<FILTERED DATA>.write[A]`.

Comment: Your solution was really straight forward and was just what I needed.